# SOAP Extension Configuration (Initialization) .NET

Tags: .net, configuration, soap-extension

I'm using SOAP Extension to encrypt/decrypt messages between server-client (Using IIS Webservices)

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.getinitializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I've known that there are 2 methods GetInitializer(Type) & GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute) to get initializer for a SOAP Extension when it be initialized.
In my case, this SOAP Extension is configured via web.config, and applied for all web methods, so I use the first once.

I want to initialize some fields (such as DB Connection String, Encryption Key, Log File Path, ...) for using in SOAP Extension, when it be initialized.

How can I do that from webservices configuration file? or other suggestion?

Thanks in advanced.